# Serialization of single quote/apostrophe giving Unicode when using JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, javascriptserializer

When I serialize a single quote/apostrophe using `JavaScriptSerializer` I always get Unicode, but I want to get the charater '. Is there any way to do this with `JavaScriptSerializer`?

I know that if I use `NewtonSoft`/`Json.NET` I have that behavior, but I want to keep using `JavaScriptSerializer`.

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var ser = jss.Serialize("'");
// ser = "\u0027"
```

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` is another option that is built in to the framework.  It doesn't escape `'` unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do it this way, using `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape()`:

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var ser = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(jss.Serialize("'"));
```

Outputs:

> "'"

...although I'm a little sceptical as to why you'd want to, as the JSON you started with is valid.